# Limits of an Improper Integral: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Is

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0
$$

when $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent?

Comment: Generally, no..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the inverse Fourier transform of $$\hat{f}(\omega)= \sum_{k\ge 1} e^{-(k^2 (\omega-k))^2}e^{i \omega e^k}\in L^1\cap L^2$$

We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{-i n e^k}=1,\lim_{n\to -\infty}\hat{f}(n)=0$.

The $e^{i \omega e^k}$ term is there to ensure that $\lim_{A\to \infty}\int_{-A}^A e^{-inx} f(x)dx$ converges to $\hat{f}(n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I using the Fourier transform of

$$
\hat{f}(\omega)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx
$$

I noticed that $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)dx=\hat{f}(0)$ and $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\sin nxdx=-\text{Im }\hat{f}(n)$.
So I wonder if examples like $\hat{f}(\omega)=e^{i\omega}$ that satisfy $\hat{f}(0)=A$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\hat{f}(n)\ne0$ could imply $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)dx=A$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\sin nxdx\ne0$?